# How to load plugin to a specific page

Tags: module, plugin

I've created a plugin, that has administrator fields that will setup things to be shown on the site page.

I was wondering if is there a way to load this plugin to a page as it's done with a module. Is there a way to set it to be shown on a specific position of a page? Or should I make a blank module that will load this plugin. If yes, how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: plugin is not a something you can load directly on a page, but you can modify content of page. can you specify what are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: @subashbasnet8 maybe plugin is not the right thing to do. i want something, where the user paste the html and css on the administrator and this html will be rendered on the page. but i can't find a way to make this plugin be loaded on the page on a specific position. what do you advise me to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood right what you said to subashbasnet8, it is a Module you want to do: create a new module, and select "Custom HTML" as Module type. Now you can edit it directly in HTML via the code editor, and it will be shown in the position you want.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out, you would want a module for this. However, the normal "Custom HTML" module will probably strip out your CSS code (and possibly parts of your HTML code as well).

I recommend a module called [Custom HTML Advanced](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/custom-html-advanced). This module will let you add HTML, CSS and even PHP without filtering.

Another useful feature is that you can reference CSS styles and CSS files into the HTML header.